# How can I slowly migrate a project from ASP .NET WebForms with VB .NET to MVC C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

At the moment I have a legacy website written in vb .net and web forms.  Its about ten years old.  I want to start to migrate components of it over to C# MVC.

My plan is to create a separate project in the solution in C# with .NET MVC, and do all the controller code etc in there.  I would need to wire up routing etc from the vb.net project though, into this project.  Eventually over time the plan is to migrate the entire project over to C# with .NET MVC.

The app uses forms auth (albeit a bit of a hacky implementation of it), so if someone logs into the legacy app, their authentication should also be recognised in the "new" project/system.

How would I do this?

EDIT: There is stuff taped into code behind en masse (mainly on row data bound etc for gridview formatting) plus a gigantic class that does absolutely everything.  Architecturally its about as bad as you could hope for.

Comment: Do you have an option of creating an entirely new project, porting features step by step, and switching to the new architecture entirely once ready?

Comment: I think it depends on how much logic is crammed into the code behind versus if the webform is very light and calls to code in other projects. What does the architecture look like? It's also possible to run an MVC and WebForms blend in the same project (as a middle step) but you still have the language diffence to deal with then.

Comment: @CoolBots not really... due to time constraints.  CRice its revolting, a huge monolithic class that does everything and a stack of code behind, plus a tonne of iframes that load different pages.  Very brittle and yuck.

Comment: @LewisCianci Then I would first make some c# projects to go against the current UI, and rewrite your non-view logic there and call it from you web forms. Once that is done its just page/view conversion and setting up routing. Constructor inject/create your classes from the new projects to make it easy to put straight into controllers later.

Comment: Just my own suggestion, ASP.NET MVC is possibly going to be legacy soon. You should consider .NET Core + Angular or React and Vue. There is no real direct conversion and its likely to be failure because alot of web form components aren't supported in MVC. My experience at the end was completely re-write the application.

Comment: Sorry, as you can already tell this is an _opinionated_ question. _You_ already have your opinions ("gigantic", "taped") so go with that. Make it "less gigantic" and more "concise" piece by piece. However "hacky" the auth is will decide whether you keep it or rebuild it (nobody here knows how "hacky").

Comment: @EdSF Well, while many different people will have an opinion on how to do it, there will still be a "right way" to port bits and pieces over to a new project

Comment: How would anyone here give you the "right way"? Nobody here knows your app, it's dependencies, ties to legacies? What you'll get are opinions based primarily on any experience they have with migrating applications, just like my _opinion_. You stated _yours_ - it's the only one that matters because you _know_ your app more than anyone here.

Comment: I don't really want to get into a fight over semantics, and you are right, there are different opinions on how to do this, but thats the nature of being a software developer, people have different opinions on how to implement the same thing.  The project as it is is a huge monolithic class that does everything, and there is a lot in code behind, and its in vb.net.  There's enough in that for someone to rough out a way forward.

Answer (score 0):

As an initial step, you can convert your VB project into C# using SharpDevelop. They have independent IDE and also Visual Studio plugin.

Comment: It doesn't work :( It produces too many errors in the conversion

Answer (score 0):

Even though you stated that you don't have time to start a new project due to time constraints, this is the best route as you will spend more time converting code than working on a new project.